# Teschl, Ordinary differential equation... Problem 5.23

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem from ordinary differential equations and dynamical systems by Gerald Teschl.

Suppose $f\in C_{p}^{1}[a,b]$. Show that for every $\varepsilon>0$,
$\vert f(x)\vert^{2}\leq \varepsilon \int_{a}^{b}\vert f'(x)\vert^{2}dx +(1/\varepsilon +1/(b-a))\int_{a}^{b}\vert f(x)\vert^{2} dx$.

Hint: $\dfrac{d}{dx}\vert f(x)\vert^{2}=2Re(f(x)f'(x))\leq 2\vert f(x)f'(x)\vert$.

I have tried many thing but nothing works, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can try so called "epsilon inequalities" (pl. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Elementary_case)

Answer (score 2):

There is some mid point $m$ in the interval satisfying the mean value theorem for
$$
\int_a^b |f(s)|^2\,ds = (b-a)\,|f(m)|^2
$$
By the fundamental theorem
$$
f(x)^2-f(m)^2=\int_m^x 2f(s)f'(s)\,ds
$$
which implies via Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
|f(x)|^2\le |f(m)|^2 + 2 \sqrt{\int_m^x|f(s)|^2ds}\sqrt{\int_m^x|f'(s)|^2ds}\le  \frac{\|f\|_2^2}{b-a}+2\,\|f\|_2\,\|f'\|_2
$$
As Serge P. commented, now apply the epsilon variant of the basic Young inequality
$$
0\le(a-bε)^2\implies ab\le\frac{a^2}{2ε}+\frac{εb^2}2
$$
with $a=\|f\|_2$ and $b=\|f'\|_2$ to get the result.

Comment: very elegant proof, thanks.